# What does \@let@token do?

Tags: macros, latex-base

In `source2e.pdf` I've seen `\@let@token` used in several places, for example in the definition of `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
  \let\reserved@d=#1%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \def\reserved@b{#3}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
```

However, I couldn't find a description of `\@let@token`, so my question is what exactly does `\@let@token` do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\@let@token` is assigned by `\futurelet` to the next token after the `\@ifnextchar`, i.e. it is the next character. The `\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch` code means "assign the next token to `\@let@token` and then process `\@ifnch`". Inside `\@ifnch` the `\@let@token` macro is tested if it is equal to the (first token of the) first argument of `\@ifnextchar`, i.e. `\reserved@d` (see the `\let\reserved@d=#1`).

So, it does nothing, but it is used as a temporary variable. In theory `\@tempa` could have been used as well but wouldn't be as save as a named special macro. The benefit here is that you can check `\@let@token` in the *false* clause of `\@ifnextchar` using `\ifx` against other tokens without going to the more complex `\@ifnextchar` macro again.

```
\@ifnextchar{\relax}{It was a relax!}{%
   \ifx\@let@token$
      It was a dollar!
   \else
     \ifx\@let@token&
        It was an ampersand!
     \else
        something else
     \fi
   \fi
}
```

This is useful for parser code as in e.g. `tikz-timing` and `ydoc`.