# How to create new commands with multiple arguments?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'd like to create a new command `\add` that accepts 2 arguments, called *entity* and *title*. In other words, the command should look like this: `\add{entity}{title}`. The output should have the following form: `\textit{entity} '{title}'`.

So if I, for example, type `\add{article}{LaTeX}` the result should be *article* 'LaTeX'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this: [Commands that may take a variable number of arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/commands-that-may-take-a-variable-number-of-arguments), also be interesting for you.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\add}[2]{\textit{#1} {`#2'}}
```

For more reading material on this, see

- [LaTeX help with `\newcommand`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_19.html); and/or
- [LaTeX/Macros wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros)

Comment: you are welcome, AND welcome to TeX.SE! :)

Comment: @Jeroen If you want correct single quotation marks for the second argument should use `#2'.

Answer (score 23):

I'm going to suggest a very different approach which might seem like a bit of overkill in this particular situation but can pay off in the long run.

I would suggest using keys to accomplish what you want.

So, I would set up keys as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/jeroen/entities/.cd,
  title/.initial=,
  entity/.initial=,
  }
\def\jeroen@set@keys#1{%%
  \pgfkeys{/jeroen/entities/.cd,#1}}
\def\jeroen@get#1{%%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/jeroen/entities/#1}}

\newcommand\Add[1]{%%
  \bgroup
  \jeroen@set@keys{#1}%%
  \textit{\jeroen@get{entity}} `\jeroen@get{title}'%%
  \egroup}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Add{title=\LaTeX,entity=article}

\end{document}
```

In the shortrun, this is a lot of overhead to create for what seems like a simple command.  But, in the long run this can pay off dividends.

In my experience, I find instances where I want to use essentially the same underlying macro, but rewriting the macro can be a pain in the neck.  For example, I might want to use the macro without calling one of its arguments; I might want to add a third argument or even an optional argument.  Using key values, it can be much easier to modify your code or improve upon implementation later.

Key values also get around the issue of remembering which argument is for which content.

By using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, you can more easily define default behaviors when a key has not been called.  For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/jeroen/entities/.cd,
  title/.initial=,
  entity/.initial=article,
  }
\def\jeroen@set@keys#1{%%
  \pgfkeys{/jeroen/entities/.cd,#1}}
\def\jeroen@get#1{%%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/jeroen/entities/#1}}
\newcommand\Add[1]{%%
  \bgroup
  \jeroen@set@keys{#1}%%
  \textit{\jeroen@get{entity}} `\jeroen@get{title}'%%
  \egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Add{title=\LaTeX,entity=article}

\Add{title=long nosed creature,entity=elephant}

\Add{title=mathematics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

An interesting example of how one can define commands with different syntax, but doing the same thing, with minumum effort.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define the keys
\keys_define:nn { jeroen/add }
 {
  title  .tl_set:N  = \l_jeroen_add_title_tl,
  title  .initial:n = {},
  entity .tl_set:N  = \l_jeroen_add_entity_tl,
  entity .initial:n = article,
 }

% The key-value interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\Add} { m }
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { jeroen/add } { #1 }
  \jeroen_add:VV \l_jeroen_add_entity_tl \l_jeroen_add_title_tl
  \group_end:
 }

% The two argument interface
\NewDocumentCommand{\add} { m m }
 {
  \jeroen_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% The main command
\cs_new:Nn \jeroen_add:nn
 {
  \textit{#1}\nobreakspace`#2'
 }

% The variant needed for the key-value interface
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \jeroen_add:nn { VV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Key-value syntax:

\Add{title=\LaTeX,entity=article}

\Add{title=long nosed creature,entity=elephant}

\Add{title=mathematics}

\medskip

Two argument syntax:

\add{article}{\LaTeX}

\add{elephant}{long nosed creature}

\add{article}{mathematics}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference between `\jeroen_add:nn` and `\jeroen_add:VV` is that the former expects two standard braced arguments and the latter uses the value of two variables passed as arguments (unbraced). It isn't really necessary in this case, because

```
\jeroen_add:nn { \l_jeroen_add_entity_tl } { \l_jeroen_add_title_tl }
```

would work the same. In other cases, creating the variant could solve many subtle problems. It is also conceptually better.

Answer (score 8):

Using `\def` should be avoided as there is no "compile type checking" whether or not the macro being defined clashes the existing macro with the same name. Use `\newcommand` instead.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}

%\def\Marco#1#2{arg1: #1 and arg2: #2} <== it is not recommended as a best practice.
\newcommand\Marco[2]{arg1: #1 and arg2: #2}

\begin{document}
\Marco{Van}{Basten}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is set to community wiki to prevent me from getting reputation points whenever you like this answer and vote it up.

Answer (score 4):

`xparse` can save life with its features some times. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Add}{mm}{\textit{#1}{} `#2'}
\begin{document}
 \Add{article}{\LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details `texdoc xparse` or visit [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net)

Comment: `details` please :-)

Comment: @azetina My typing is not trustworthy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`\def\Add#1#2{\textit{#1}\ '{#2}'}`. Name `\Add` seems to be safer.

Or, if one dislikes `\def`, `\newcommand{\Add}[2]{\textit{#1}\ '{#2}'}`

Comment: Not `\def`, please!

Comment: Those 'in the know' are aware, but `\def` is the right way *only when working with Plain TeX -- a format entirely separate from LaTeX*. (This question, as asked, could apply to either.)

Comment: @egreg There are cases where `\def` can be exactly what you need. For instance with the `subpreambles` option active when including multiple `standalone` files containing different implementations for identically named commands, using `\def` ensures that each file uses its own version.

Comment: @Casimir If you like to live dangerously.