# Script {} in latex

Tags: macros, amsmath, scripts

So I'm writing my master thesis and I was wondering whether there was a way to script a custom `\Laplace` function in Latex. I want to write `\Laplace(input)` and get the output `\Laplace \{ input \}` as my Latex output. My function is defined like this now

```
\newcommand{\Laplace}{\mathscr{L}}
```

. Instead of writing `\Laplace \{ input \}` on every place I need my Laplace

Comment: Welcome! This question is not clear at all. Please add an example of what you'd like to obtain, possibly with a compilable snippet.

Comment: So what i want is that everytime i write \Laplace i get auto \Laplace \{  \}

Comment: Or in other word i want my \newcommand{\Laplace}{\mathscr{L}} to be a function such that \newcommand{\Laplace(input) }{\mathscr{L}} { \{   (input)   \} }

Comment: sorry this question is impossible to understand. Do you mean you want your editor to add `\{\}` after you type `\Laplace` (why?) or are you asking for a tex defintion, and if so what do you want it to do?

Comment: `\newcommand\Laplace[1]{\mathscr{L}\{#1\}}`  then `\Laplace{A}` would make ℒ{_A_} ?

Comment: Basically [macros - How to create new commands with multiple arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/how-to-create-new-commands-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 3):

We can define it as `\newcommand\Laplace[1]{\ensuremath{\mathscr{L}\mleft\{#1\mright\}}}` where the `\mleft\{` and `\mright\}` will make the braces scale appropriately with taller arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\newcommand\Laplace[1]{\ensuremath{\mathscr{L}\mleft\{#1\mright\}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\Laplace{\delta(t)}&=1\\
\Laplace{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}t^{n-1}e^{-at}}&=\frac{1}{(s+a)^n}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It might be useful to define an inverse laplace command as well: `\newcommand\InvLaplace[1]{\ensuremath{\mathscr{L}^{-1}\mleft\{#1\mright\}}}`

EDIT: Thanks to @Mico for recommending `\mleft` and `\mright` from `mleftright` for removing the extra space between the Laplace operator and the start of the braces.

Comment: When i use this in my document i get a new page on the top. and say Laplace symbol {1 } on that page. And also when i use it in the document i dont get the braces around it

Comment: The use of `\left\{` creates too much whitespace between `\mathscr{L}` and `\{`. (Check out `\ln(x)` or `\sin(theta)` -- it's no accident that there's no whitespace between the function name and the parenthesis.) To get around this problem, you could load the `mleftright` package and replace `\left\{#1\right\}` with `\mleft\{#1\mright\}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I just updated the answer to include `mleftright`.

Comment: @Lopehert the code here should work, you could add a similar small example to your question that shows your problem

Comment: +1: I did not know about the `mleftright` package, good to know.

Comment: Works now! Thanks alot :)

Comment: What is the reason for using the `mathrsfs` package? It seems to ver quite old (1999?).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It is for the `\mathscr` "L", though perhaps there is a newer package for it that I don't yet know about.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - The `mathrsfs` -- "rsfs" is short for "Ralph Smith's formal script" -- math font package provides heavily sloped "script"-style uppercase letters. The fact that the .sty file hasn't been updated in 20 years is of little consequence.