# Is there any way to pass variables to commands?

Tags: macros, arguments

Right now I'm doing some math homework that has lots of ordered pairs. Being lazy, I got tired of writing `\langle x, y \rangle` and so I was wondering if there's a way to define a command, say `\ordered`, that receives parameters `x, y` and returns `\langle x, y \rangle` . For example `\ordered{1, 3}` would return [image].

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Near duplicate of [macros - How to create new commands with multiple arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/how-to-create-new-commands-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: Or [arguments - Easy way to convert \command{x}{y} to \command{x,y} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647164/easy-way-to-convert-commandxy-to-commandx-y?noredirect=1&lq=1), depends on what you want exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
\newcommand{\ordered}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}
```

which will also cover ordered triples, quadruples and so on. You can do

```
\ordered{x,y}
\ordered{x,y,z}
```

and the output would be as expected.

It's not just laziness! Suppose at some point your coauthor tells you that angle brackets are awful and round parentheses *must* be used (you're not in the position to contradict your coauthor). Having a command for the thing is the best, because you comply with the *diktat* by modifying into

```
\newcommand{\ordered}[1]{(#1)}
```

and recompile. But maybe your coauthor has a different idea: use semicolons instead of colons.

Not a big deal: change the code into

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ordered}{m}
 {
  \langle % or (, maybe
  \clist_use:nn { #1 } { ; }
  \rangle % or ), maybe
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and recompile. No change at all in the document input.

Explanation: you need `\ExplSyntaxOn` to access the `expl3` programming layer; `\NewDocumentCommand` is better in this context, but also `\newcommand{\ordered}[1]` would do. With `\clist_use:nn` we tell LaTeX to digest a comma separated list of items and deliver it with semicolons in between items.

Comment: I think any solution like this should include an interface for scaling the brackets.

Comment: @Gaussler I don't think this is needed for the particular case of ordered tuples.

Comment: Depends on the vertical size of what you are ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
\def\ordered#1{\langle #1\rangle}
```

This defines a macro `\ordered` with one parameter `#1`. If you use e.g. `\ordered{1,3}` then the parameter `#1` is `1,3` and the macro expands to `\langle 1,3\rangle`.