# How to print `n` arguments in a command?

Tags: macros, xetex, lists

This is what I want to do:

```
\newcommand{\foobar}[n]{%
  \hspace*{1.5ex}-\hspace{1ex}\emph{#n}\\%
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
\foobar
  {Hello}
  {World}
```

However this doesnt actually work. I want

```
\hspace*{1.5ex}-\hspace{1ex}\emph{#n}\\%
```

To appear for as many arguments as I supply to `\foobar`. How do I do this?

**NOTE**

To clarify, what I want finally is this:

```
- Hello
- World
- N number of other arguments
```

Comment: Please, make clearer what you want; in any case you can't specify an arbitrary number of arguments. Usually one solves it by giving as single argument a comma separated list.

Comment: How do I split by comma given a list?

Comment: Choose a duplicate by looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=variable+number+arguments

Comment: How your theoretical `\foobar` macro recognizes that `{World}` (in your example) is the last parameter? I. e. that n=2. Is there a symbol or mark for that?

Comment: No. I assumed LaTeX had some sort of iterator for rendering an arbitrary number of arguments. I guess this isnt the case?

Comment: a macro argument only needs to be surrounded by braces if it is more than one tokens so `\foobar abc` is typically legal with a b and c being `#1`, `#2`, `#3`. You need some kind of terminator but as others have said the latex syntax here should be `\foobar{a,b,c,d,e}`

Comment: Any automaton (LaTeX or another) must know which argument is the last one. How to recognize the last argument or the number of arguments? Human must say something about it.

Comment: Related/(duplicate?) [Commands that may take a variable number of arguments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118114/2693).

Answer (score 1):

This is the 'traditional' comma-separated-value approach, using `etoolbox` and storing the csv-arguments to a list and displaying it. The `\showme` command is just an example what to do with the individual values.

Improved solutions are based on a precise definition of the question.

But as stated already in the comments: There must be some information which is the last argument, an arbitrary number isn't possible this way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\showme}[1]{%
#1

}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
\def\templist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\templist}{#1}
\forlistloop{\showme}{\templist}
}


\begin{document}

\mycmd{a,b,c,d,e,f,some longer text}

\end{document}
```

[image]