# Variable number of arguments in a command

Tags: macros, arguments

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\test[2]{#1\textsuperscript{#2}}
\begin{document}
The player ended as no.~\test{1}{} and her friend came in \test{2}{nd}.
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

How can I change the `\test` command so that I'm abel to switch between one or two arguments?

(I would like to be abel to write `\test{1}` instead of `\test{1}{}`.)

Comment: Optional arguments for LaTeX2e commands are given in square brackets!

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry. I mixed things up; I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: For easy usage of optional arguments: `\NewDocumentCommand` ;-)

Comment: So you'd like to have `\test{1}` and `\test{2}[nd]`?

Comment: By the way, this is rather a case of `fmtcount`

Comment: @egreg Please see comment to Christian Hupfer's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288020/15874).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You *might* want to be able to use `\test{1}` and `\test{2}{nd}`, but I'm recommending not to.

Comment: @egreg Okay. Can you explain why?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Joseph already told you: if an argument is optional, treat it as such.

Comment: While it is possible to do this it is a really bad idea to do it in a latex2e context.  LaTeX2e commands _never_ take a variable number of `{}` arguments. A major aim of the system is to give a consistent interface to arguments. If an argument is optional it should be in square brackets.

Comment: Related: [macros - Commands that may take a variable number of arguments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/commands-that-may-take-a-variable-number-of-arguments/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternative interface using `*` (say):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@test}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\@@test}[1]{\ordinalnum{#1}}
\newcommand{\test}{\@ifstar\@test\@@test}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test{1} \test*{1}

\test{2} \test*{2}

\test{11} \test{12} \test{21}
\end{document}
```

The above command definition is also possible using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{s m}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{#2}{\ordinalnum{#2}}}
```

Comment: Great! What if I want the starred version to give the ordinal number?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Then use `\newcommand{\test}{\@ifstar\@@test\@test}` or `\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{s m}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\ordinalnum{#2}}{#2}}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You can accept any answer *that helped you the most*.

Comment: Okay. I think that Christian is rather childish so I'll let him have the 15 points reward but I'll remember your advise for next time.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: :)

Answer (score 8):

With `xparse` the feature can be done easily with the `g` optional argumen t specifier, but optional arguments should be done with `[...]`, i.e. use `o` rather, in my point of view!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mg}{#1\IfValueT{#2}{\textsuperscript{#2}}}
\begin{document}
The player ended as no.~\test{1} and her friend came as \test{2}{nd}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to be abel to write `\test{1}` and `\test{2}{nd}` (or `\test{5}` and `\test{8}{th}`, ect.).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: That's easy: Use `g` instead of `o` as optional argument specifier!

Comment: I actually like Werner approach better (even though I asked for the solution you have given).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You asked for this and I provided this -- now you unaccept. I am sure you know  that is **not** kosher at all.

Comment: I didn't knew that but we can't have that you are upset about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand\test[2][]{#2\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\textsuperscript{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
The player ended as no.~\test{1} and her friend came ind \test[nd]{2}.
\end{document}
```