# How to write a macro that takes a variable number of arguments

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I am trying to make a new command called `\com` which can do the following:

- If no argument is provided to `\com`, `$\com$` produces the symbol `$\lambda$`.
- If one argument is provided, e.g. `$\com{f}$`, the macro produces `$\lambda [f]$` (with square brackets).
- If two arguments are provided, e.g. `$\com{f}{x}$`, the macro produces symbol `$\lambda {f}(x)$` (with curly braces and round parentheses, resp.).

I have tried if else commands from the other posts but I am unable to make this work.

If some one can show me how to do this, I would be grateful.

Comment: This is a command with two optional arguments, effectively.

Comment: That is true. But I won't know how to program this.

Comment: Should your third bullet say `$\lambda \{f\}(x)$`?

Comment: You can even aim higher and it's easier with `xparse`.  `\com` = `\lambda`; `\com[f]` = `\lambda[f]`; `\com{f}(x)` = `\lambda\{f\}(x)`. That way your code resembles the output and is easier to understand.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Variable number of arguments in a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/288019/5764)

Comment: Related: [macros - Commands that may take a variable number of arguments - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/commands-that-may-take-a-variable-number-of-arguments/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is quite easy with `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand`, having two optional arguments, however, you need to check for their existence.

Please note that `oo` could be replaced by `gg` to allow for optional `{}{}` arguments, but that's not recommended, but see below in this answer as an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\com}{oo}{%
  \lambda%
  %Check if the first arg is given
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    % Now check if has a 2nd argument as well. 
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% Yes, the 2nd one is present, use {f}(x) style
      \{#1\}(#2)%
    }{% No, use [f] style
      [#1]% 
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\com$

$\com[f]$

$\com[f][x]$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with `gg` type (use it with care!) and another optional argument to use that instead of `\lambda`**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\com}{oo}{%
  \lambda%
  %Check if the first arg is given
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    % Now check if has a 2nd argument as well. 
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% Yes, the 2nd one is present, use {f}(x) style
      \{#1\}(#2)%
    }{% No, use [f] style
      [#1]% 
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\comother}{O{\lambda}gg}{%
  #1%
  %Check if the first arg is given
  \IfValueT{#2}{%
    % Now check if has a 2nd argument as well. 
    \IfValueTF{#3}{% Yes, the 2nd one is present, use {f}(x) style
      \{#2\}(#3)%
    }{% No, use [f] style
      [#2]% 
    }%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

$\com$

$\com[f]$

$\com[f][x]$


$\comother$

$\comother{f}$

$\comother{f}{x}$

% Now with \beta instead of \lambda

$\comother[\beta]$

$\comother[\beta]{h}$

$\comother[\beta]{h}{y}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Of course, the syntax uses the standard LaTeX convention of optional arguments in square brackets, in this case for both optional arguments.

Also, the OP implied that the command should be used *not* in math mode, so I have accommodated that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\com[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1$\lambda$\else\def\firstarg{#1}\comhelp\fi}
\newcommand\comhelp[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1$\lambda [\firstarg]$%
  \else$\lambda \{\firstarg\}(#1)$\fi}
\begin{document}
\com\quad\com[f]\quad\com[f][x]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a version that instead oeprates in math mode, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\com[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\lambda\else\def\firstarg{#1}\comhelp\fi}
\newcommand\comhelp[1][\relax]{\ifx\relax#1\lambda [\firstarg]%
  \else\lambda \{\firstarg\}(#1)\fi}
\begin{document}
$\com\quad\com[f]\quad\com[f][x]$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It works as a preprocessor: The Lua function `comscan` runs at a very early stage of processing, *before* TeX gets to do its usual work. The Lua function find all instances of `\com` and replaces with a different macro, depending on whether `\com` is found to have 0, 1, or 2 arguments.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function comscan ( s )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\com(%b{})(%b{})" , "\\lambda\\{%1\\}(%2)" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\com(%b{})", "\\lambda[%1]" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "\\com(%A)" , "\\lambda%1" )
  return ( s )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", comscan, "comscan" )
\end{luacode}
\providecommand{\command}{aaa} % dummy command
\begin{document}
$\com{f}{x}$, $\com{g}$, $ \com $, \command
\end{document}
```

Comment: One might also consider using the token scanner to do this without using the callback ...

Comment: @JosephWright - An excellent idea. :-) Do you want to provide a separate answer to show to achieve the OP's objective via the token scanner? (I'm afraid my knowledge of Lua(La)TeX isn't deep enough in this regard.)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are going to use non-standard arguments, I think you could aim to a more easier to read code. That way `[f]` outputs brackets, `{f}` outputs curly braces (here's where you avoid typing `\{f\}`) and `(f)` outputs parenthesis.

With this minimal code, you ensure that `\com`, `\com[f]` and `\com{f}(g)` behave as you would expect (the only intelligence given to the command is to convert `{f}` to `\{f\}`, the rest is left unchanged and works as you would expect).

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\com{g}{\lambda\IfValueT{#1}{\{#1\}}}
```

---

If you really need those to be treated as arguments and you need a bit more intelligence, then you need to define the full command

```
\NewDocumentCommand\com{o}{\lambda\IfValueTF{#1}{[#1]}{\comaux}}
\NewDocumentCommand\comaux{gd()}{\IfValueT{#2}{\{#1\}}\IfValueT{#2}{(#2)}}
```

Comment: I mentioned the usage of `g` already yesterday in my answer (+1 anyway ;-) )

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, my answer was more into the “use natural markup” which can be easy with `xparse`; true that it uses `g` as your answer, but that was not the core of my answer so that's why I posted it.