How to do nothing if argument is empty?
I have a feeling this will be very simple, but I've been unable to find out how to do it.
Consider this code:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}[2] {
\begin{itemize}
\item #1
\item #2
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\items{Foo}{Bar}
\end{document}

The output looks like this:

Now, let's say that argument 2 is empty:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}[2] {
\begin{itemize}
\item #1
\item #2
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\items{Foo}{}
\end{document}

We get this, unsurprisingly:

The question is, how do I make it so that the second item does not show up at all, like this?


The kernel has an IfEmptyTF, or something, it is in usrguide.pdf, will check when in the office. Otherwise ifblank from etoolbox

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288019/variable-number-of-arguments-in-a-command or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359010/how-to-write-a-macro-that-takes-a-variable-number-of-arguments or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/commands-that-may-take-a-variable-number-of-arguments

See also \IfNoValueTF from the xparse package, although it is only for optional arguments.

You could also consider etoolbox's list processing capabilities using an interface like \items{Foo, Bar}. See this example.

You can use, e.g., \ifstrempty from etoolbox:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\items}[2] {
\begin{itemize}
\item #1
\ifstrempty{#2}{}{\item #2}%
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
Foo:
\items{Foo1}{Foo2}
Bar:
\items{Bar1}{}
\end{document}

Note: \ifstrempty does not expand the arguments and a space like in \items{Foo}{   } is not empty. For empty or space, you can replace \ifstrempty by \ifblank (see the etoolbox documentation for more information about these and similar commands) or the newer LaTeX kernel command (2022-06-01 or newer) \IfBlankTF.
There are other packages with similar features, e.g., scrbase:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrbase}
\newcommand{\items}[2] {
\begin{itemize}
\item #1
\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{}{\item #2}%
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\items{Foo1}{Bar1}
\items{Foo2}{}
\end{document}

scrbase also provides a \Ifstr that expands the argument. See the KOMA-Script documentation for more information.
But you could also do something tricky with a variable number of arguments:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}{\begin{itemize}\processitems}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\processitems}[1]{\item
  #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\processitems}{\end{itemize}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Foo:
\items{Foo1}{Foo2}{Foo3}
Bar:
\items{Bar1}{Bar2}
Poo:
\items{Poo}
\end{document}


But because this is not really LaTeX like, you can also use a variable number of optional arguments for the 2nd, 3rd, … nth:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}{\begin{itemize}\processitems}
\NewDocumentCommand{\processitems}{mo}{
  \item #1
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\processitems{#2}}{\end{itemize}}
}
\begin{document}
Foo:
\items{Foo1}[Foo2][Foo3]
Bar:
\items{Bar1}[Bar2]
Poo:
\items{Poo}
\end{document}

The result is the same as above.
If you need it only for two argument, using one optional instead of mandatory second argument would also be a common solution:
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{\items}{mo}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item #1
  \IfValueT{#2}{\item #2}
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
Foo:
\items{Foo1}[Foo2]
Bar:
\items{Bar1}
\end{document}


For only two argument in {…} with the second argument is optional, you can use the g argument type, which is only available with (deprecated) package xparse:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\items}{mg}{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item #1
  \IfValueT{#2}{\item #2}
  \end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
Foo:
\items{Foo1}{Foo2}
Bar:
\items{Bar1}
\end{document}

Result is the same as above.

The first one did the trick.

Like @daleif mentioned in his comment, you can use a check built into the kernel to see whether the argument is empty and act accordingly. There is no \IfEmptyTF, but you can use \IfBlankTF instead which will also be true if the argument only contains spaces.
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}[2]{%
  \begin{itemize}%
    \item #1%
    \IfBlankF{#2}{\item #2}%
  \end{itemize}%
}
\begin{document}
\items{Foo}{}
\end{document}

An alternative version that accepts arbitrary many items in a LaTeX-friendly syntax:
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \items { m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}
      \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \item
    \end{itemize}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Single item is harder: \items{{Foo}}

Multiple items is simple and very flexible: \items{{Foo}{Bar}{Baz}}
\end{document}


When I try to compile with pdflatex, this fails with ! Undefined control sequence. \items #1#2->\begin {itemize}\item #1\IfBlankF                                                 {#2}{\item #2}\end {itemize} l.9 \items{Foo}{}?

@KristianNordestgaard - Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it? The reason I ask this question is because the answer works without a hitch on my TeXLive2024 distribution (with all updates installed).

@Mico pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021).

@KristianNordestgaard For \IfBlankTF, \IfBlankT, \IfBlankF you need at least LaTeX 2022-06-01. For older LaTeX kernels you can use etoolbox → my answer.

@KristianNordestgaard you can use \ExplSyntaxOn\cs_new_eq:NN \IfBlankF \tl_if_blank:nF\ExplSyntaxOff in your preamble in TL 2021 and the answer should work.

Mico, I am sure your suggestion works, but I approved @cabohah's answer as that's the one I could run on my ancient system. Thanks!

@KristianNordestgaard though my name is not Mico that's totally fine, you decide what you accept.

Simple:
\newcommand{\items}[2]{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item #1 \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\item #2\fi
  \end{itemize}
}

Next, how to do the same with three or more items? What when you go beyond the nine allowed arguments?
Let's be a bit more general. You have to do something with a list of arguments which can be from zero to any number. For instance, build an itemized list (or an enumerated list, or gather a bunch of formulas).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processarguments}{mmmO{}m}
 {% #1 = pre, #2 = post, #3 = template, #4 = separator, #5 = list of items
  \nordestgaard_processargs:nnnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nordestgaard_processargs:nnnnn
 {
  % populate the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
  \tl_map_inline:nn {#5}
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
     {% we want to apply the template on the items
      \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {##1}
     }
   }
  % define the processing command to the template
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {#3}
  % issue the 'pre' tokens
  #1
  % use the sequence
  \seq_use:Nn \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq {#4}
  % issue the 'post' tokens
  #2
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

One item
\processarguments{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item #1}{
  {Foo}
}

Two items
\processarguments{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item #1}{
  {Foo}
  {Bar}
}

Three items
\processarguments{\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}{\item #1}{
  {Foo}
  {Bar}
  {Again!}
}

We can gather formulas
\processarguments{\begin{gather}}{\end{gather}}{#1}[\\]{
  {(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)}
  {x+y=y+x}
  {xy=yx}
}

\end{document}


Of course you can build on this and your \items command could be defined as
\newcommand{\items}[1]{%
  \processarguments{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item ##1}{#1}%
}

Just note ##1 because we're inside a definition.
Or even better, see the code below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\processarguments}{mmmO{}m}
 {% #1 = pre, #2 = post, #3 = template, #4 = separator, #5 = list of items
  \nordestgaard_processargs:nnnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nordestgaard_processargs:nnnnn
 {
  % populate the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
  \tl_map_inline:nn {#5}
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq
     {% we want to apply the template on the items
      \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {##1}
     }
   }
  % define the processing command to the template
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__nordestgaard_processargs_do:n {#3}
  % issue the 'pre' tokens
  #1
  % use the sequence
  \seq_use:Nn \l__nordestgaard_processargs_items_seq {#4}
  % issue the 'post' tokens
  #2
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% now we define a few instances
% first your \items
\NewDocumentCommand{\items}{m}{%
  \processarguments{\begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize}}{\item ##1}{#1}%
}
% next a better one
\NewDocumentCommand{\xitems}{O{itemize}m}{%
  \processarguments{\begin{#1}}{\end{#1}}{\item ##1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

One item
\items{
  {Foo}
}

Two items
\items{
  {Foo}
  {Bar}
}

Three items
\xitems[enumerate]{
  {Foo}
  {Bar}
  {Again!}
}

\end{document}


With this syntax, the input just requires two braces more, but accommodates any number of items.

The classical method of testing at TeX primitive level if an argument is empty is \ifx ?#1? and you must suppose that ? never occurs as the first token of #1. If #1 is empty then the test is reduced to \ifx ?? and this is true because "?" is equal to "?". If #1 isn't empty (for example #1 is abc) then the test looks like \ifx ?abc? and because ? isn't equal to a the following text is skipped until \else of \fi is reached.
In your example, the item text will never begins by ^ because this token is used in math mode only. So, your test should be:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\items}[2] {
\begin{itemize}
\item #1
\ifx ^#2^\else \item #2\fi
\end{itemize}
}
\begin{document}
\items{Foo}{}
\end{document}

If you wat to implement universal expandable test of #1 is empty, use \if^\detokenize{#1}^. The \if primitive expands \detokenize and it converts all tokens to catcode 12 (or 10 for spaces), so the token ^ with catcode 7 will never be the first token of \detokenize output.
