# Macro that takes a variable number of arguments, and creates a table with one row per argument

Tags: macros, recursion

I am trying to create a macro that takes a variable number of arguments and creates a table where each argument becomes one row; so assuming the command is called `dynamictable`, calling it like this

```latex
\dynamictable{One & Two}{Three & Four}...{N-1 & N}
```

should produce:

```
One   Two
Three Four
...
N-1   N
```

I've taken inspiration from
[this blog post](https://davidyat.es/2016/07/27/writing-a-latex-macro-that-takes-a-variable-number-of-arguments/) and transitively [answers to this question on tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118114/commands-that-may-take-a-variable-number-of-arguments). However, I've only been able to generate *one row* without errors with the MWE below - which is hardly very dynamic!

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dynamictable}[1]{%
    \begin{supertabular}[l]{c l}
    #1 \checknextline
    \end{supertabular}
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{\\}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{#1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
% This attempt gives error: Misplaced alignment character &. 
%\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{#1\\\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}\par
% Error: Misplaced alignment character &.
%\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}\par

\end{document}
```

**Question**: How can the above example be fixed to generate more than one row? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367979/latex-foreach-in-tabular-environment

Comment: Do you really believe that `\dynamictable{a & b}{c & d}` is better and easier to maintain than ``a & b \\ c & d``?

Comment: @egreg Right, I thought of that too after making the simplification that does everything with `\checknextline` (no need for `\gobblenextline`). If we make this recursive `\checknextline` take a delimited argument as opposed to a brace-delimited one, we are back to a `tabular`-like syntax, and I'm not sure of the usefulness of all this—apart from trying to improve one's LaTeX error diagnosing and programming skills. :-)

Comment: (well, with a delimited argument, there could be problems in case of nesting, though—the kind of problems that brace-delimited arguments prevent)

Comment: @egreg, no i do not :-) It's for a custom template, where I'd like the table logic to be separated from the content

Comment: @trolle3000 Still `\dynamictable{ a & b \\ c & d \\ e & f }` seems more practical and much easier to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [pointed out by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497622/macro-that-takes-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-creates-a-table-with-one-ro/497630#comment1256625_497622), what we gain from such a `\dynamictable` command accepting an “arbitrary number of arguments”, as compared to using standard tabular markup where rows are terminated by `\\`, is not very clear. But let's study it as an exercise. :-)

## What happens with your code

The error you get is due to the fact that your `\checknextline` call is immediately followed by `\end{supertabular}`.As a consequence, after `\dynamictable` has gobbled and inserted the first argument `(1,1) & (1,2)`, `\checknextline` finds that the next token is the `\end` from `\end{supertabular}`; as it is not `\let`-equal to a `\bgroup`, `\checknextline` inserts `\\` and doesn't recurse. So, the `supertabular` environment finishes, then TeX finds the second “argument” in the input stream. In fact, for TeX, this is not an argument but a braced group. TeX finds the `&` inside this group, and since we are not inside any alignment anymore (`tabular` & friends), this character token of category code 4 (alignment tab) is invalid, which gives the error:

```latex
./orig.tex:22: Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.22 \dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) &
```

## How to fix it

Let's leave `supertabular` out of the game for now, it just complicates things. The first attempt at a fix could be (ugly, but shows the reasoning):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dynamictable}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[l]{c l}
    #1 \checknextline
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{\\}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{#1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This fails with:

```latex
./a.tex:16: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.16 \dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}
```

because `\checknextline` calls `\gobblenextline` which inserts its `#1` (the second “argument”) without prepending any `\\`. Therefore TeX finds two alignment tab tokens (`&`) on the same line of the alignment, which at this point looks like:

```latex
(1,1) & (1,2)(2,1) & (2,2)
```

This doesn't match the preamble you specified (at least 3 columns would be required), hence the error. Inserting the appropriate `\\` can be done with:

```latex
\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{\\ #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
```

With a document body like this:

```latex
\begin{document}

\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

this works flawlessly.

But this is not beautiful syntax, so as the next step, one could make an environment that inserts the `\end{tabular}` itself at the end, instead of a command that has to be followed by `\end{tabular}`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dynamictable}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}[l]{c l}
    #1\checknextline
}{%
    \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{\\ #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dynamictable}{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}
\end{dynamictable}

\end{document}
```

This works, but:

- error reporting can be improved by using `\tabular` and `\endtabular` inside our custom environment, instead of `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}` (this way, if there is an  error while processing the `dynamictable` environment, it will be reported as occurring inside this environment as opposed to within `tabular` which the end-user didn't explicitly use);
- taking the first braced group as an argument of the environment doesn't seem very useful; the tabular contents could as well belong to the environment body.

Implementing these little improvements and customary whitespace handling for environments, we obtain:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dynamictable}{%
  \tabular[l]{c l}
  \checknextline
}{%
  \unskip
  \endtabular
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{#1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\\ \gobblenextline}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dynamictable}
{(1,1) & (1,2)}
{(2,1) & (2,2)}
\end{dynamictable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

`\@ifnextchar` has the property of ignoring space tokens when looking ahead for the “next char”, which allowed us to put the two braced groups on separate lines in order to improve readability.

Alas, this doesn't work with `supertabular` (I haven't checked why), but it seems this package has been superseded by `longtable` for many use cases, and the approach described above does work with `longtable`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{dynamictable}{%
  \longtable[l]{c l}
  \checknextline
}{%
  \unskip
  \endlongtable
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{}}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{#1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\\ \gobblenextline}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{dynamictable}
{(1,1) & (1,2)}
{(2,1) & (2,2)}
\end{dynamictable}

\end{document}
```

(screenshot identical to the previous one)

## Retaining the command syntax

As pointed out by Skillmon, it is possible to retain the syntax of a command for `\dynamictable` as opposed to making it an environment (I believe I prefer the environment syntax, but you are of course free to choose whichever you prefer). For this, all that needs to be done is to insert the appropriate `\endtabular` or `\endlongtable` from within `\checknextline` and `\gobblenextline` when they detect that there is no other braced group following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dynamictable}{%
  \longtable[l]{c l}
  \checknextline
}

\newcommand{\checknextline}{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\gobblenextline}{\endlongtable}%
}
\newcommand{\gobblenextline}[1]{%
  #1\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\\ \gobblenextline}{\endlongtable}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dynamictable
{(1,1) & (1,2)}
{(2,1) & (2,2)}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you may write the body as:

```latex
\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}
```

if you want. In case you use this approach, you can use `\relax` to terminate the table and be sure not to mistakenly take a following opening brace as the start of another line:

```latex
\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}\relax
{\bfseries This doesn't belong to the table.}
```

[image: Screenshot]

That said, at this point, you should realize that we are back to using an end delimiter, only with less readability than with `\end{dynamictable}`. Thus, I still prefer the environment-based approach.

Comment: Why don't you simply put `\end{tabular}` inside the second argument of `\@ifnextchar`?

Comment: @Skillmon Because I didn't think about it. :-) I believe I prefer the environment syntax for readability of the source, but your suggestion does work; I have therefore mentioned it at the end of my answer (cf. *Retaining the command syntax*). Thanks!

Comment: @Skillmon The downside with this approach is that an opening brace from the text that follows the table would be mistakenly interpreted as the start of a new table line. I've added the suggestion of using `\relax` at the end of the “arguments in variable number” to make sure this doesn't happen, but this leads us back to using an end delimiter, only with less readability than with `\end{dynamictable}`. So, I still prefer the environment approach—which doesn't change the fact that your remark was quite relevant to the question.

Comment: That is correct, but this wouldn't be an issue most of the time, and the few cases it could, the OP should be aware of how to circumvent this.

Comment: @Skillmon Right, I mostly agree. If `\@ifnextchar` were to expand tokens while trying to ignore space tokens before the potential “next char”, that would be more problematic, but that is not the case. However, the OP could still have bad surprises if he used a macro finishing with `\dynamictable{...} ... {...}` and the macro *call* were followed by an opening brace. Then he ought to add `\relax` (for instance) at the end of the replacement text of his macro to be sure to terminate the pseudo-argument  grabbing regardless of what follows the macro call.

Comment: @frougon, thanks for breaking down the fix step by step

Comment: @trolle3000 I'm very glad I didn't write it for someone who won't read it (which unfortunately happens)!

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, I realized that the approach with two commands (`\checknextline` taking no argument and `\gobblenextline` taking one argument) would behave better, if properly implemented, in case the number of arguments (braced groups) is zero. So, I reverted to this way of processing the variable number of arguments in my last edit. Of course, you might want to completely short-circuit the `tabular` or `longtable` in such a case; but at least, the various samples in my last edit should all compile correctly and produce an empty table when there are no braced groups following.

Answer (score 3):

The following grabs arguments until the next token is not an opening brace. Additionally it takes a variable number of columns and sets them all centred. You can use an optional argument to explicitly specify the table preamble. This one uses `tabular` but I think you can easily change it to another table environment:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{\RepeatCols}{!{\d@llarend&\span\@gobbletwo}}
\newcommand*\dynamictable@grab
  {%
    \futurelet\dynamictable@tok\dynamictable@grab@a
  }
\newcommand*\dynamictable@grab@a
  {%
    \ifx\dynamictable@tok\@sptoken
      \dynamictable@grab@eatspace
    \fi
    \dynamictable@grab@b
  }
\newcommand*\dynamictable@grab@eatspace[1]
  {%
    \def\dynamictable@grab@eatspace\fi##1#1{\fi\dynamictable@grab}%
  }
\dynamictable@grab@eatspace{ }
\newcommand*\dynamictable@grab@b
  {%
    \ifx\dynamictable@tok\bgroup
      \dynamictable@grab@c
    \fi
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\newif\ifdynamictable@first
\def\dynamictable@grab@c\fi\end#1#2%
  {%
    \fi
    \ifdynamictable@first\else\\\fi #2
    \dynamictable@grab
  }
\newcommand\dynamictable[1][c \RepeatCols c]
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
    \dynamictable@firsttrue
    \dynamictable@grab
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}\par
% Error: Misplaced alignment character &.
\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}\par
\dynamictable{(1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3)}{(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3)}\par

\end{document}
```

The following is an alternative implementation, which takes an arbitrary number of arguments, but enclosed by an additional level of braces.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{\RepeatCols}{!{\d@llarend&\span\@gobbletwo}}
\begingroup
\xdef\dynamictable@mark
  {%
    \unexpanded\expandafter
      {%
        \csname dynamictable Error: mark expanded.\endcsname
        \dynamictable@mark
      }%
  }
\endgroup
\long\def\dynamictable@end\fi\@firstofone#1%
  {%
    \fi
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\newcommand\dynamictable@iterator[1]
  {%
    \ifx\dynamictable@mark#1%
      \dynamictable@end
    \fi
    \@firstofone{#1\\\dynamictable@iterator}%
  }
\newcommand\dynamictable[2][c \RepeatCols c]
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{#1}%
    \dynamictable@iterator#2\dynamictable@mark
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\dynamictable{{(1,1) & (1,2)}}\par
% Error: Misplaced alignment character &.
\dynamictable{{(1,1) & (1,2)}{(2,1) & (2,2)}}\par
\dynamictable{{(1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3)}{(2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3)}}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

(output of both code versions)

Comment: Highly elegant, thanks!