# Itemize command with variable number of items

Tags: macros, itemize

I'm looking to create a command that I can give a variable number of inputs, and it will place them into an itemized list. Something like

```
\myitemize{First item}{Second item}{Third item}
```

would produce

[image]

While something like

```
\myitemize{First item}{Second item}
```

would produce

[image]

I'm also not picky on formatting. It could be something like

```
\myitemize[First item, second item, third item]{3}
```

I just don't want to have to manually change the `\begin{itemize} \end{itemize}` to include another line and another `\item`.
Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand why "invent" new syntax for the list `itemize` if existed is so deliberated designed ... (clear and easy to use)

Comment: This is good if you like to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is implemented in [Macro that takes a variable number of arguments, and creates a table with one row per argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497622/73317). Be sure to read all the comments there. In particular, this is possibly *not a great markup style.*

The second approach is easy to implement with `expl3` (you don't even need to specify the number of elements), for instance like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__ryanj_tmp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ryanj_output_items:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ryanj_tmp_seq {#1}
    \seq_use:Nn \l__ryanj_tmp_seq { \item }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mystrangeitemize { m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}
    \item
    \ryanj_output_items:n {#1}
    \end{itemize}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \mystrangeitemize{First item, Second item, Third item,
                    {Item, containing, commas.}}
\end{document}
```

`\mystrangeitemize` could also be implemented this way:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand \mystrangeitemize { m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}
    \ryanj_output_items:n { {}, #1 }
    \end{itemize}
  }
```

(the added empty item causes the first `\item` command to be output).

In both cases, if you want to be able to declare items containing multiple paragraphs (`\par` tokens must then be acceptable in the argument of `\mystrangeitemize`), replace `m` with `+m` in `\NewDocumentCommand \mystrangeitemize { m }`.

[image: Screenshot]

`etoolbox`'s `\docsvlist` can also be used for this purpose, and you may also possibly see someone post a solution based on `listofitems`. :-)

Comment: Such a nice suggestion...