# Xparse Adding backslash after each command

Tags: xparse

I want to write a command.

This is the example the commands should achieve:

```
\begin{alignat}{1}
Hello \\
Hello two \\
Hello three
\end{alignat}{1}
```

This should the commands look like:

```
\mycommand {
\command{Hello}
\command{Hello two}
\command{Hello three}
}
```

\mycommand has one argument and this will include a list of commands.
It will put a `\begin{alignat}{1}` before all commands and a `\end{alignat}{1}` after all commands. Between each of the commands it will insert a `\\` (after the last command no `\\` is inserted and this is the difficult part).

In this example the `\command` is

```
\newcommand{\command}[1]{#1}
```

The Question is how do i write `\mycommmand`

Comment: Where will you be using `\mycommand`? Inside a `tabular`?

Comment: no it is like a macro for a table. and \command will insert a row

Comment: Could you show a use-case? Sometimes working with macros inside tables could be tricky, so having a use-case could help with getting proper answers.

Comment: That last case you say is too easy: `\newcommand\mycommand[1]{\begin{alignat}{1}#1\end{alignat}}` and `\newcommand\command[1]{#1\\}`.

Comment: yes thats the general idea but the problem is that this will insert a $\\$ after the last \command and this is what i want to omit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an implementation of `\mycommand` and `\command` that provides what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Some text before.
\begin{alignat}{1}
  \text{Hello} \\
  \text{Hello two} \\
  \text{Hello three}
\end{alignat}
Some text after.

\noindent
\hrulefill

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1 \end{alignat}%
}%

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \text{Hello} \\
  \text{Hello two} \\
  \text{Hello three}
}%
Some text after.

\noindent
\hrulefill

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1\null \end{alignat}%
}%
\def\@afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}%
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\text{#1} \@ifnextchar\null{}{\\}}%
\makeatother

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \command{Hello}
  \command{Hello two}
  \command{Hello three}
}%
Some text after.

\end{document}
```

An additional `\null` token is inserted at the end of `\mycommand`'s argument, and used as a check in `\command` using [`\@ifnextchar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57788/5764).

Comment: With `xparse` (which is in the title), it would be `\NewDocumentCommand\command{mt\null}{\text{#1}\IfBooleanF{#2}{\\}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Doing it with just `xparse` facilities is complicated. Here's an implementation using some functions from `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_mycommand_lines_seq
\seq_new:N \l_mycommand_output_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_mycommand_lines_seq { \command } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_mycommand_lines_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_mycommand_output_seq \l_mycommand_lines_seq
   { \exp_not:n { \command { ##1 } } }
  \begin{align}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mycommand_output_seq { \\ }
  \end{align}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_blank:nT { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\command}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\mycommand{
\command{Hello}
\command{Hello &= two}
\command{Hello &= three}
}

\end{document}
```

The input is split at `\command` tokens; white space will be automatically trimmed. The first element in the sequence is popped off, as it will be empty. Then the sequence is mapped to reinsert `\command` before the items (but a different macro could be used. Then the resulting sequence is *used* with `\\` in between any two items.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you declared the variables `\l_mycommand_lines_seq` and `\l_mycommand_output_seq` _outside_ `\mycommand`'s definition? Do `\l_`-variables need to be declared outside the “environment” in which they are actually set?

Comment: @PierPaolo Yes, they should, or you would redeclare them every time the macro/environment is called.

Answer (score 0):

This adds a `\\` after each token in the argument.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\mycommand{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn {#1} {##1\\}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: this is not correct. it insert too many \\

Comment: Well, then your question might be not as clear as you think. What I understood (before your edit) that you wanted `\mycommand{\commanda \commandb \commandc}` to `\commanda\\\commandb\\\commandc`. Now, from your new edit I don't understand anything (at least before I understood something, altough it was wrong). Try making a better and *exact* example of what you want.