# Conditional code based on token

Tags: conditionals, optional-arguments, xparse

This is a follow-up question to [Xparse Adding backslash after each command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224456/5764).

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) allows for conditional tokens to be inserted into the parameter text for a macro using the `t<token>` directive (from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf):

> **`t`** An optional `<token>`, which will result in a value `\BooleanTrue` if `<token>` is present and `\BooleanFalse` otherwise. Given as `t<token>`.

However, why do the following two implementations - one using (La)TeX and the other using LaTeX3 - not produce the same result?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\begin{document}

% LaTeX implementation
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1\null \end{alignat}%
}%
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\text{#1} \@ifnextchar\null{}{\\}}%
\makeatother

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \command{Hello}
  \command{Hello two}
  \command{Hello three}
}%
Some text after.

\noindent
\hrulefill

% LaTeX3 implementation
\RenewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ m }{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1\null \end{alignat}%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\command}{ m t\null }{\text{#1} \IfBooleanF{#2}{\\}}%

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \command{Hello}
  \command{Hello two}
  \command{Hello three}
}%
Some text after.

\end{document}
```

The conditional token seems to be picked up appropriately when adding `\tracingmacros1` to the LaTeX3 section. However, I'm not sure why `\null` is "never found", leading to `\BooleanFalse` (and therefore a `\\`) even in the last statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2e command skips white space while looking for the character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\begin{document}

% LaTeX implementation
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1\null \end{alignat}%
}%
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\text{#1} \@ifnextchar\null{}{\\}}%
\makeatother

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \command{Hello}
  \command{Hello two}
  \command{Hello three}
}%
Some text after.

\noindent
\hrulefill

% LaTeX3 implementation
\RenewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ m }{%
  \begin{alignat}{1} #1\null \end{alignat}%
}%
\RenewDocumentCommand{\command}{ m t\null }{\text{#1} \IfBooleanF{#2}{\\}}%

Some text before.
\mycommand{
  \command{Hello}
  \command{Hello two}
  \command{Hello three}}%
Some text after.

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...even in math mode, strange.

Comment: @Werner `\@ifnextchar` doesn't know whether it is in math mode or not, (nor does xparse) they are looking for tokens. the fact that a space token doesn't produce a typeset result in vertical or math modes isn't relevant at this level.