# Why is escaped # breaking my command?

Tags: macros, errors, hyperref, description

I have created the following two commands:

```
\newcommand{\termExplanation}[1]{\item[#1]\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\newTerm}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\emph{#1}}}
```

In my text, I use `\newTerm{Term 3}`, and somewhere else in the document is my term explanation:

```
\begin{description}
    \termExplanation{Term 1} description...
    \termExplanation{Term 2} description...
    \termExplanation{Term 3} description...
    ...
\end{description}
```

Working fine so far. But now I wanted to introduce the new Term `C#`. Of course I used `\newTerm{C\#}` and `\termExplanation{C\#}`. 
But it fails:

```
% occurs at \newTerm{C\#}
Missing \endcsname inserted. ..., die Programmiersprache ist \newTerm{C\#}
Extra \endcsname. ..., die Programmiersprache ist \newTerm{C\#}
% occurs at \termExplanation{C\#}
Missing \endcsname inserted. ....1}{8}{Begriffserklärung}{section.A.1}{}}
Extra \endcsname. ....1}{8}{Begriffserklärung}{section.A.1}{}}
```

When compiling for the first time, the text has two `C#`, the second one is emphasized and there is no link on either one. The explanation output is just fine. When recompiling there is no pdf output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't use `\#` in a label.

Comment: that's sad....
thought i could avoid writing `C-Sharp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the content of `\label` doesn't handle these special characters well.  The easiest alternative would be to simply not use the special characters and define variants of your commands that allow an arbitrary label in such case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\termExplanation{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\termExplanation@opt}{\termExplanation@noopt}
}
\def\termExplanation@opt[#1]#2{%
  \item[#2]\label{#1}%
}
\def\termExplanation@noopt#1{\termExplanation@opt[#1]{#1}}

\def\newTerm{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\newTerm@opt}{\newTerm@noopt}%
}
\def\newTerm@opt[#1]#2{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\emph{#2}}%
}
\def\newTerm@noopt#1{\newTerm@opt[#1]{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\termExplanation[chash]{C\#} Hello, World!
\termExplanation{lorem} Lorem Ipsum!
\end{description}

\newTerm[chash]{C\#} \newTerm{lorem}
\end{document}
```

To understand what this bit of code those, I recommend you have a look at:

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)
- [Understanding \@ifnextchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar)

as they provide very comprehensive answers.  Otherwise, the `\def` command is the TeX primitive behind `\newcommand` and offers a little more flexibility in the way arguments can be given, though definitely in most cases use `\newcommand`.

A better option alternative, as suggested by egreg in the comments, is:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\termExplanation{\@dblarg\termExplanation@opt}
\def\termExplanation@opt[#1]#2{\item[#2]\label{#1}}
\newcommand\newTerm{\@dblarg\newTerm@opt}
\def\newTerm@opt[#1]#2{\hyperref[#1]{\emph{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

As a last note, it really seems to me like you are creating a glossary.  If so, then you should also have a look at the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package.  I provide a small MWE of the `glossaries` package below:

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\loadglsentries{glossary}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

You can now refer to glossary terms with \gls{permittivity} and
\gls{permeability}.  You can even get the plural with \glspl{permittivity} and
get the capitalized version with \Gls{permittivity} and \Glspl{permeability}.

\clearpage
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

and `glossary.tex`:

```
\newglossaryentry{permeability}{
    name={permeability},
    plural={permeabilities},
    symbol={\(\mu\)},
    parent={},
    description={A measure of how easy it is to form a magnetic field in a medium.}
}

\newglossaryentry{permittivity}{
    name={permittivity},
    plural={permittivities},
    symbol={\(\varepsilon\)},
    parent={},
    description={A measure of the resistance encountered when forming an electric field in a medium}
}
```

and the output:

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Note that the `glossaries` package requires an additional run of `makeglossaries` in order to process the glossary entries.

Comment: is glossaries easy to use? I struggled with integrating bibtex before, so now I hesitate to use big packages when i can achieve my wanted result with some easy macros

Comment: and also, could you give a little explanation to your answer? I' m not that familiar with LaTeX, e.g. I don't know what `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do ^^

Comment: your solution doesn't work: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \termExplanation@noopt. ...anation@noopt#1{\termExplanation@opt[#1]#2` - I tried to resolve this myself bad had no luck, don't know the syntax that well

Comment: @TheFlow0360 I updated my answer to include a minimal example of how to use `glossaries`.  Also, I there was a typo in one of the definitions where it should've been `[#1]#1` but instead I wrote `[#1]#2`.

Comment: still not working properly for me, but I think I'll use glossaries anyways, so not a problem - thx for the extensive answer

Comment: @TheFlow0360 I added a more complete example showing how the code goes in the document and how the function should be used.

Comment: I tried it like you wrote there, and it didn't work - maybe i just misstyped somewhere, but I just rewrote everything to use glossaries, so I won't try it out again

Comment: @JP-Ellis Please, guard against unprotected end-of-lines!

Comment: By the way, it should be `\newcommand\termExplanation{\@dblarg\@termExplanation}` followed by `\def\@termExplanation[#1]{#2}{\item[#2]\label{#1}}`

Answer (score 6):

You can't generally use `\#` in a label, because it doesn't expand to a character. However, in this particular situation a workaround is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\termExplanation}[1]{%
  \item[#1]%
  \begingroup
  % locally disable \#
  \def\#{?hashmark?}%
  \phantomsection\label{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\newTerm}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % locally disable \#
  \def\#{?hashmark?}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\hyperref[#1]}\x{\emph{#1}}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\termExplanation{C\#} Hello, World!
\termExplanation{lorem} Lorem Ipsum!
\end{description}

\newTerm{C\#} \newTerm{lorem}
\end{document}
```

The trick is to tell LaTeX that `\#` in a label writes `?hashmark?`; the same trick is used to retrieve the label before `\hyperref` does its job.

Don't forget `\phantomsection` that creates a suitable anchor.

[image]

Comment: \phantomsection is a really good hint, i was missing this - but since I now use glossries anyways, it wasn't that important. Still, thx for your answer