# \@ifnextchar considering whitespace

Tags: white-space

Somewhat related to [Understanding \@ifnextchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar) question...

Is there any variant of `\@ifnextchar` which does not skip whitespace, i.e. which takes whitespace into account? For example, one would like to test whether `a` is immediately followed by `b`.

Comment: `\futurelet`,  `\@ifnextchar`  is a latex wrapper around `\futurelet` where skipping space is the main thing it does,

Comment: As an addition you can look here: https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ifnextok/ifnextok.pdf.

Comment: // amsmath (technically amsgen) defines `\new@ifnextchar` but this appears to be an internal undocumented macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package [`ltxcmds`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds) defines `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` that does not skip spaces. From its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/ltxcmds.pdf):

> `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` `{⟨char⟩}` `{⟨yes⟩}` `{⟨no⟩}`
>
> Macro `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` behaves like macro `\ltx@ifnextchar`
>   with the exception that optional spaces are not supported before char.
>   Since 2011/04/14 v1.19.