# "missing \begin{document}" when setting new command

Tags: macros, errors, compilation-error

I'm trying to get this command into my LaTeX document but it causes the compiler to fail, saying `"Missing \begin{document}"`:

`\newcommand{\C*}{\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace}`

I have also tried using `\C0` instead of `\C*` thinking the asterisk might cause an issue, but to no change in the error message. The error message also says I can't use `\mathbb{.}` outside math mode, which I am not trying to do. Using `\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}` is working fine in my document, I don't understand the difference to be honest and thus I can't figure out how to fix the issue.

Comment: command names have to be letters or a single non letter you can not have a command `\C*` or `\C0`

Comment: Don't worry about the math error, the first is important. That one got the typesetting engine running and you *are* now tryng to use `\mathbb` outside of math mode. Fixing the first error will not throw LaTeX off the wagon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command names have to be letters or a single non letter you can not have a command `\C*` or `\C0`

After the first couple of expansions your input is more or less the same as this, which gives the same error.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\C}{}{*}{\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

So `\C` gets defined

```
 \newcommand{\C}{}
```

then it starts a paragraph of text with the symbol `*` which gives the missing document error as you can not typeset text before `\begin{document}`

```
{*}
```

Then if you scroll past that it tries to typeset

```
{\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace}
```

which gives an error because it is not in math mode.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake now. I‘m pretty new to using LaTeX and didn‘t know commands can only consist of letters. Thank you!

Comment: Latex is just sooo outdated, not even numbers are allowed in command names, which is totally legal in any other programming language. Instead of `\myCommand2` it must be called `\myCommandTwo`, it's just riduculous...

Comment: @SimSon you are free to use other languages if you prefer.

Answer (score 5):

You already know why it doesn't work. If you really want to have `\C` to do `\mathbb{C}` and `\C*` to do `\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}`, you can do it easily:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\C}{s}{%
  \mathbb{C}\IfBooleanT{#1}{\setminus\{0\}}%
}
```

With `\IfBooleanT{#1}` we check for the presence of `*`.

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\C}{s}{%
  \mathbb{C}\IfBooleanT{#1}{\setminus\{0\}}%
}

\begin{document}

The set of complex numbers is $\C$. If we remove~$0$
we get $\C*$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer `\C0`, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\C}{t{0}}{%
  \mathbb{C}\IfBooleanT{#1}{\setminus\{0\}}%
}

\begin{document}

The set of complex numbers is $\C$. If we remove~$0$
we get $\C0$.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

> can't figure out how to fix the issue

If by "fix" you mean define a command using one "other" character, like the * or 0, you could use `\@ifnextchar`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
  \makeatletter
    % What to do if there is a *
    % Need an argument to "eat" the *.
    % (so in the below, the argument #1
    % is the asterisk)
    \newcommand\CStar[2]{GotAStar and #2}
    % What to do otherwise
    \def\CNoStar{\relax}
    % Define \C and delegat what should happen
    % if it's followed by a *
    \def\C{\@ifnextchar*\CStar\CNoStar}
  \makeatother
  \C*{ARG}
\end{document}
```

The answers following question explains what happens here pretty good: [Understanding \@ifnextchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar)

Comment: You could also use `\@ifstar`, which lets you define `\CStar`, more naturally, as a command with one argument.

Comment: Sure, but wouldn’t work for `0`, right?

Comment: Also, maybe you could do `\catcode \`*11` ?

Comment: Of course, `\@ifstar` wouldn’t work with other characters than the star—I hadn’t noticed that part of the question.  In any case see @egreg’s answer for the most elegant, LaTeX3-flavored solution.  As for setting ``\catcode`*=11``, since `\@ifnextchar` uses an `\ifx` test, I would expect this—among other things—to break all uses of the `\@ifstar` macro, which is already defined in the format with a “`\catcode 12`” `*` character.

Comment: Agree with the elegance of @egreg's answer!