# Optional Arguments Based on Position

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

We all know how `\newtheorem` works. It takes a third optional argument and it matters where you put it:

```
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
```

is different to

```
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[thm]
```

I'm getting into macros and would like to replicate it in my own way. I understand optional arguments for LaTeX and have read this TeX article https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-1-2/tb70eijk.pdf but I found it overwhelming and wondered:

*Exactly how was* `\newtheorem` *defined?*

As I understand `\newcommand` I don't know how this position dependence could be done from LaTeX. I know I can solve this problem with xparse etc. I am just curious exactly how the maker(s) did this without xparse.

Answer (score 5):

The default approach for `\newcommand` is to have the optional argument as the *first* element

```
\mycmd[<opt>]{<arg1>}...{<argn>}
```

However, one can chain `\newcommand`s in a way that makes placement of the optional argument in any way you want:

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}{\firstcmd}
\newcommand{\firstcmd}[1]{first #1\space \secondcmd}
\newcommand{\secondcmd}[2][opt]{second (opt: #1) #2}

%...

\mycmd{1st}[OPT]{2nd}
```

[image]

In the above, `\mycmd` just provides the "user interface" to `\firstcmd` which takes a single mandatory argument. At the end of `\firstcmd`, we chain `\secondcmd` which requires 2 arguments, the first of which is optional. Since the two are chained (`\secondcmd` is called at the end of `\firstcmd`), their arguments can be chained. To that end, it seems from a user perspective that `\mycmd` takes 3 arguments, with the middle one being optional.

You'll note this string of commands defined and chained within [`ltthm.dtx`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltthm.dtx) or [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) (the LaTeX kernel) when searching for `\newtheorem`:

```
%%% From File: ltthm.dtx
\def\newtheorem#1{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@othm{#1}}{\@nthm{#1}}}
\def\@nthm#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@xnthm{#1}{#2}}{\@ynthm{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@xnthm#1#2[#3]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}\@newctr{#1}[#3]%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{%
       \expandafter\noexpand\csname the#3\endcsname \@thmcountersep
          \@thmcounter{#1}}%
     \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#1}{#2}}%
     \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}
\def\@ynthm#1#2{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\@definecounter{#1}%
     \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#1}}%
     \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#1}{#2}}%
     \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}
\def\@othm#1[#2]#3{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocounterr{#2}}%
    {\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
    {\global\@namedef{the#1}{\@nameuse{the#2}}%
  \global\@namedef{#1}{\@thm{#2}{#3}}%
  \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}}
\def\@thm#1#2{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@ythm{#1}{#2}}{\@xthm{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@xthm#1#2{%
  \@begintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\ignorespaces}
\def\@ythm#1#2[#3]{%
  \@opargbegintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#3}\ignorespaces}
\def\@thmcounter#1{\noexpand\arabic{#1}}
\def\@thmcountersep{.}
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist
   \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\itshape}
\def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2\ (#3)}]\itshape}
\def\@endtheorem{\endtrivlist}
```

Each definition is called using conditions as part of `\newtheorem` and `\@nthm` using [`\@ifnextchar[`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57788/5764). These conditions are implicit when defining a macro using `\newcommand`; `\newtheorem` uses `\def` and therefore explicitly checks to see if the following argument starts with a `[` (which should be optional).

These tricks are simplified by [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) where you can mix optional arguments within a definition without chaining. For example:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{m O{opt} m}{first #1\space second (opt: #2) #3}
```

displays the same output as defined above using chaining.

Answer (score 5):

How are commands with an optional argument defined in the LaTeX kernel way?

The key function is `\@ifnextchar`, which tests the following token (gobbling spaces) and can perform different actions. See [Understanding \@ifnextchar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57788/4427) for more information.

In your case we want a command `\foo` that does different things when called as `\foo{m1}{m2}`, `\foo{m1}[o1]{m2}` or `\foo{m1}{m2}[o2]`. The two optional argument are mutually exclusive.

Let's start: the macro `\foo` will collect the first mandatory argument and test for `[`:

```
\def\foo#1{\@ifnextchar[{\foo@firstopt{#1}}{\foo@nofirstopt{#1}}}
```

It's very important that `\@ifnextchar<token>{<true>}{<false>}` is at the end.

We now have to define `\foo@firstopt`, which has to absorb another mandatory argument; the `[` is not removed from the main input list, so we can do

```
\def\foo@firstopt#1[#2]#3{%
   <the code for the "o1" case>%
   \@ifnextchar[{\foo@badsecondopt}{}%
}
```

At the end we add code for testing the presence of the second optional argument, to raise an error and remove the offending part:

```
\def\foo@badsecondopt[#1]{<raise an error>}
```

Now let's tackle `\foo@nofirstopt`; we need to check for a trailing optional argument:

```
\def\foo@nofirstopt#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\foo@secondopt{#1}{#2}}{\foo@nosecondopt{#1}{#2}}%
}
```

Now it's easy:

```
\def\foo@secondopt#1#2[#3]{%
  <the code for the "o2" case>%
}
\def\foo@nosecondopt#1#2{%
  <the code for the "no optional arguments" case>%
}
```

The description of `\newtheorem` is a bit more complicated, because the kernel tries to avoid code duplication.

Note how already absorbed arguments can be carried on to the next stage.

How can we do the same with `xparse`?

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m o m o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {% no o1
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}%
       {% no o2
        <code for the "no optional arguments" case>%
       }%
       {% o2
        <code for the "o2" case>%
       }%
    }%
    {% o1
     <code for the "o1" case>%
     \IfNoValueF{#2}{<error message>}%
    }%
  }
```

The two mandatory arguments are referred to as `#1` and `#3`, the two optional arguments as `#2` and `#4`.

Answer (score 2):

Werner [in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509239/118714) already exhibited and explained the code sequences of the LaTeX 2ε-kernel where `\newtheorem` is defined.

As you can see in his answer, this is not done by means of `\newcommand`.

To be honest, I cannot get all too excited about macros with many optional arguments in square brackets.

Often it is worth considering to use a package like [keyval](https://ctan.org/pkg/keyval) or [xkeyval](https://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) or [processkv](https://ctan.org/pkg/processkv) or [pdfkeys](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) or whatever for key=value-processing, and to have only one optional argument where you can pass a key=value-list where the keys and values denote which values you wish to differ in which ways from their default-values.

Be that as it may.

In any case I strongly recommend to define macros in a way where optional arguments are never preceded and/or trailed by other optional arguments. In other words: Optional arguments should never be directly adjacent to each other.
An exception to the rule could be a scenario where providing adjacent optional arguments at the further right only makes sense when all adjacent optional arguments at the further left are provided also.

In case you are interested, here is my own small personal toolkit for defining
macros which process several optional arguments.

The gist is:

With my toolkit mechanisms for processing several optional arguments consist of two things:

- A "Wrapper"-macro which first collects optional and non-optional-arguments into a list of non-optional arguments maintained via macro `\UD@CollectedArguments` and then passes the expansion of `\UD@CollectedArguments` to the internal macro which does the actual work. The "wrapper-macro" must be robust/non-expandable as by LaTeX 2ε-kernel-design macros that process optional arguments cannot be carried out in pure-expansion-contexts.
- An internal macro which processes all arguments as non-optional arguments and does the actual work.

The single macros:

- The macro `\UD@ClearCollectedArguments` defines the list `\UD@CollectedArguments` to be empty.
- The macro `\UD@PassAndClearCollectedArguments{⟨internal macro⟩}` passes the list of arguments held in `\UD@CollectedArguments` to `⟨internal macro⟩` and defines `\UD@CollectedArguments` to be empty.
- The macro `\UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{⟨default value⟩}{⟨continue⟩}` collects an optional argument whose default value is `⟨default value⟩` and attaches the tokens which form that optional argument, as another non-optional argument, to the list of non-optional-arguments that is held in `\UD@CollectedArguments` and then delivers `⟨continue⟩`.
- The macro `\UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{⟨continue⟩}` collects a non-optional argument and attaches the tokens which form that non-optional argument, as another non-optional argument, to the list of non-optional-arguments that is held in `\UD@CollectedArguments`, and then delivers `⟨continue⟩`.

Thus you can gather up arguments by nesting calls to `\UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments`/`\UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments` within the `⟨continue⟩`-argument. In the innermost nesting-level the `⟨continue⟩`-argument holds the `\UD@PassAndClearCollectedArguments`-directive for passing the collected arguments to the `⟨internal macro⟩` which does the actual work.

```
\documentclass[landscape, a4paper]{article}

%-------------------[adjust margins/layout for the example]--------------------
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=2cm
\marginparsep=.125\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\advance\textwidth-2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=2cm
\footskip=.5\topmargin
{\normalfont\global\advance\footskip.5\ht\strutbox}%
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\pagestyle{plain}
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=\bigskipamount
%------------------[eof margin-adjustments]------------------------------------

\makeatletter
%========[This is my personal toolkit for gathering optional arguments]========
% (As macros with optional arguments by LaTeX2e-kernel-design cannot be used in
%  full-expansion-contexts, let's gather arguments within a macro
%  \UD@CollectedArguments and in a last step pass the arguments gathered in
%  that macro to an internal macro which does process non-optional
%  arguments only.)
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@CollectedArguments{}%
\newcommand\UD@ClearCollectedArguments{\long\gdef\UD@CollectedArguments{}}%
\newcommand\UD@PassAndClearCollectedArguments[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\UD@CollectedArguments}{\UD@ClearCollectedArguments#1}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{<default value>}{<continue>}
%
% Grabs an optional argument whose default value is <default value>
% , wraps it in curly braces and adds it to the macro \UD@CollectedArguments
% and delivers <continue>.
%..............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments[2]{%
  \@testopt{\UD@@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{#2}}{#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{%
  \begingroup
  % Check the availability of the \unexpanded-primitive:
  \edef\@tempa{\meaning\unexpanded}%
  \edef\@tempb{\string\unexpanded}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {% <- \unexpanded is available:
    \long\def\UD@@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments#1[#2]{%
      \xdef\UD@CollectedArguments{\unexpanded\expandafter{\UD@CollectedArguments{#2}}}%
      #1%
    }%
  }{% <- \unexpanded is not available:
    \long\def\UD@@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments#1[#2]{%
      \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\expandafter
      \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@}}{%
        \toks@\expandafter{\UD@CollectedArguments{#2}}%
        \xdef\UD@CollectedArguments{\the\toks@}%
      }%
      #1%
    }%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{<continue>}
%
% Grabs a non-optional argument, wraps it in curly braces and adds it to the
% macro \UD@CollectedArguments and delivers <continue>.
%..............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments[2]{%
   \UD@@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{#1}[{#2}]%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Explanation:
%
% You can gather up arguments within the macro \UD@CollectedArguments by nesting
% calls to \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments / \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments
% within the <continue>-arguments.
%========[eof personal toolkit]================================================

% Now let's use the personal toolkit for creating a mechanism which
% gathers 9 arguments, whereof the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th and 9th are optional
% while the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th are non-optional:
%
\newcommand\ProcessNineArgumentsInternal[9]{%
  \textbf{Arguments are:}\\
  \texttt{[#1]\{#2\}[#3]\{#4\}[#5]\{#6\}[#7]\{#8\}[#9]}
}%
% Now the argument-gathering wrapper for \ProcessNineArgumentsInternal -
% !!!!! this must be robust !!!!
\@ifdefinable\ProcessNineArguments{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\ProcessNineArguments{%
    \UD@ClearCollectedArguments
    \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{DEFAULT 1}{%
      \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{%
        \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{DEFAULT 2}{%
          \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{%
            \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{DEFAULT 3}{%
              \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{%
                \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{DEFAULT 4}{%
                  \UD@AddNonOptArgToCollectedArguments{%
                    \UD@AddOptArgToCollectedArguments{DEFAULT 5}{%
                      \UD@PassAndClearCollectedArguments{\ProcessNineArgumentsInternal}%
                    }%
                  }%
                }%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\ProcessNineArguments{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}| yields:\\
\ProcessNineArguments{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}

\verb|\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}| yields:\\
\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}

\verb|\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}[5th opt]| yields:\\
\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}{4th non-opt}[5th opt]

\verb|\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}[2nd opt]{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}[4th opt]{4th non-opt}[5th opt]| yields:\\
\ProcessNineArguments[1st opt]{1st non-opt}[2nd opt]{2nd non-opt}[3rd opt]{3rd non-opt}[4th opt]{4th non-opt}[5th opt]


\end{document}
```

[image]