# Where's the mandatory argument of sectioning commands?

Tags: sectioning, sourcecode, latex-base

I was looking in the file [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and I noted there is no mandatory argument in the definition of `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\paragraph` commands

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
           {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
           {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
           {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
%etc.
```

i.e. the commands are all in the form `\newcommand\foosection{\@startsection{foo}{foo}{foo}...}`. Then I looked into the `\@startsection` definition and there is the `\@sect` command which takes 8 arguments but I didn't quite understand very well which one represents the heading to be printed for the section neither how can a command can be defined with a mandatory argument without declaring it.

Do you know how is the title of the section entering in its definition and if the mandatory argument is in some way implicitly defined inside the command definition itself?

Comment: The answer to how to declare a macro that seems to take an argument, without declaring that it does is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take the example of `\section` (all of them behave more or less the same, except for `\chapter` and `\part`). The definition is:

```latex
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
           {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
           {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

so when you do `\section` you are actually doing `\@startsection` with a bunch of parameters, which will be used to know: `#1`: the name of the command, counter to be used, etc.; `#2`: the level of the section heading; `#3`: the indentation of the heading, in case of a `\paragraph`-type heading; `#4`: space before the heading, `#5`: space after the heading, and `#6`: style. There are a few conditions when `#4` or `#5` are negative to produce run-in headings, like `\paragraph`, but I'll not get into that here.

If you look at the definition of `\@startsection` you will see it takes these 6 arguments:

```latex
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
```

At this point, all that was done is the `\section` command: TeX has not looked at anything beyond that yet. Now, at the end of the definition of `\@startsecion` you see:

```latex
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}
```

here, the `\@ifstar` checks for a `*` following `\section`.

**If there is a `*`** then four of the arguments of `\@startsection` are passed to `\@ssect`: `\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}`. But `\@ssect` has 5 arguments:

```latex
\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{%
```

so the fifth argument is the section title. Here no optional argument is expected. Try `\section*[optional]{mandatory}` to see.

**If there is no `*`** then `\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}` is used.

`\@dblarg` checks for a following `[`...`]`-delimited argument (`<optional>`) and then a `<mandatory>` argument. If there is a `[`, then `\@dblarg{<code>}[<optional>]{<mandatory>}` expands to just `<code>[<optional>]{<mandatory>}`, otherwise it expands to `<code>[<mandatory>]{<mandatory>}`. In short, it duplicates the mandatory argument if no optional argument is given; thus the name `\@dblarg`.

After `\@dblarg` is completed, you are left with:

```latex
\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[<optional-or-copy-of-mandatory>]{<mandatory>}
```

where the (possible) optional argument is taken from the input stream, right after `\section`, and the mandatory argument right after that.

Finally, `\@sect` is expanded, which takes 6 arguments, a `[`...`]`-delimited argument, and another argument:

```latex
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
```

finishing the argument parsing of `\section`.

---

In short, the `\section` command itself does not take any argument. However it expands to a sequence of commands that will parse the input stream and handle possible optional arguments and use them. A closely related question was asked earlier today on the subject of optional arguments. You may find it useful: [Optional Arguments Based on Position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509236/134574)

Comment: Very good write-up! +1

Comment: Perfectly explained, got all my doubts solved. Can't expect a more complete answer.