# \renewcommand with only one argument, inside \newcommand - why does this work?

Tags: macros, arguments

I have seen the following definition in a class file (which we use internally):

```latex
\newcommand{\@TitleBackground}{default}
\newcommand{\titlebackground}{\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}}
```

This provides `\titlebackground` as a command for changing `\@TitleBackground`, but how/why does it work?
I would understand it if the second line was

```latex
\newcommand{\titlebackground}[1]{\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}{#1}}
```

but why does it work also without the argument, i.e, with `\renewcommand` having onle one parameter?

And does the shorter version has some advantages or disadvantages over the longer one?

Comment: Because when you do `\titlebackground{something}`, TeX expands `\titlebackground` to `\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}` and you have `\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}{something}`, which is _slightly_ faster than grabbing the argument once, and passing it again to `\renewcommand` (which is not wrong either).

Comment: Although the macro you're asking about is different, the principle is the same as explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509471/134574.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `\newcommand{\titlebackground}{\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}}`, the following happens when `\titlebackground{whatever}` is processed:
`\titlebackground` is replaced by its expansion, so TeX will restart from

```
\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}{whatever}
```

and eventually do `\def\@TitleBackground`.

With `\newcommand{\titlebackground}[1]{\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}{#1}}`, upon finding `\titlebackground{whatever}` TeX will start expanding `\titlebackground`; since now this is a macro with an argument, TeX absorbs it and replaces the whole `\titlebackground{whatever}` with the replacement text, getting at

```
\renewcommand{\@TitleBackground}{whatever}
```

as before. So the difference is that in the second case `{whatever}` is looked at as an argument one more time than in the first version.

The difference is negligible. On my machine, doing a job like in the second case one million times require 1/100 of a second longer than the first way.

Comment: So, they will get exactly the same result, will basically the same speed - but the shorter one hides the fact that the command needs an argument - not only from humans, but also from editors like TeXstudio that actually parse \newcommand .. correct?

Comment: @MichalKaut Yes, the second way is clearer under several aspects, clarity is usually preferable to efficiency at all costs.