# Definitions for sections, subsections and subsubsections (+chapter?)

Tags: macros, document-classes, article, documentclass-writing, definition

I want to change the commands of the article/ book class and want to know how sections, especially in the article class but also in the book class, are defined.

I think it is something like this?:

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

I want to alter them a little bit and add some commands using `\renewcommand` in a class (.cls) I'm currently writing. Where can I find the other section definitions? Can someone provide a link or the code in an answer?

Comment: That's the definition of `\subsection`. All of `\(sub(sub))section` and `\(sub)paragraph` have similar definitions (in the LaTeX standard classes, at least), which depend on `\@startsection`. `\chapter` and `\part`, in classes which have them, are different. Here's a description of how `\@startsection` works, if that's what you're looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509474/134574. What exactly do you want to change in the sectioning commands?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I want to add a command I define, which I call `\sectioncolor`, `\subsectioncolor` etc. to the last line, so that I can use another command; `\setsectioncolor{blue}` before `\begin{document}`, and then all section headlines will appear blue.

Comment: You can find the definition of \@startsection in source2e.pdf (CTAN).  The tricky bit is that it has 7 arguments.  The first five are shown and the last two are stolen from \section etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, but I want to know how `\section{}` is defined specifically in the article class so it will not appear different when I `\renew` it.

Comment: It would be easier to do that with `titlesec`.

Comment: @Bernard yes, I know. The other reason I want to know is to make other changes as well later, not only color.

Comment: With titlesec you can change everything that can be done directly, in a simpler way.

Comment: You can find that in article.cls (on my computer it is located in the `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base` folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the whole article.cls file here (where the sections is defined): https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co

I do not use a downloaded version of LaTeX, only online (Overleaf) so the command `kpsewhere article.cls` is no use because the file is not stored on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Along these lines?

```
\newcommand{\subsectioncolor}{...}

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\subsectioncolor\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

but taking due account of how coloring works.

For the code for chapters look in the code for the appropriate class (book, report, memoir, etc)

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I want to do. I only need to figure out how `\section` and `\subsubsection` is defined.

Comment: @Vebjorn `kpsewhere article.cls' gives you the path to the file.