# How to define a command like `\node` of `tikz` package

Tags: macros, latex3

With `tikz`, we can write

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{mystyle} = [rectangle, text centered]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [mystyle] at (0, 0) (mylabel) {mytext};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to define a command that can work like `\node`?

As a subquestion of that, what are the terminologies to talk about commands like `\node` in the aspect of language? A parallel example in `Python` is that when we define a function, we have positional arguments, keyword arguments, decorators .etc as follows:

```python
@decorator
def function(pos_only_arg1, pos_only_arg2, /, arg1, arg2, *, kw_only_arg1, kw_only_arg2):
    ...
```

Is there similarly straight forward illustration for defining commands in `latex`? In the case of `\node`, I am particularly interested in the syntax `at (0, 0)` and `[mystyle]`, which it seems impossible to implement with just `\newcommand`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! The key point is consecutive use of `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` (see lines starting with `\def\tikz@fig ode` and `\def\tikz@@scan@fig` in [`tikz.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex)), which is similar to [`\@ifnextchar`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/understanding-ifnextchar).